# how to fix id key not found in pentaho spoon

Tags: etl, pentaho, data-mining, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

im trying to create a fact table from my dimension tables using foreign keys and primary keys
but when im trying to execute it gives me that id key couldnt be found
[id key coudlnt be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlHeZ.png)

but i m pretty sure that i have all the id keys like in the following images :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEHg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhmaK.png)

im looking for a solution to  fix id key coudnt be found